# Restcomm Connect build failed in Ubuntu due to missing Apiviz 1.3.2GA

Tags: maven, build, jboss, ubuntu-16.04, restcomm

I'd appreciate any advice to overcome this build issue.

First of all apologies if this is too basic, straightforward, but I'm afraid I'm not skilled in Maven.

### Please see below the last excerpt of the build log:

```
 [exec] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
 [exec] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [exec] [INFO] Total time: 55.460 s
 [exec] [INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-03T00:13:22+02:00
 [exec] [INFO] Final Memory: 24M/79M
 [exec] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [exec] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.6.1:javadoc (default-cli) on project restcomm-connect.provisioning.number.api: An error has occurred in JavaDocs report generation:Unable to resolve artifact:groupId = 'org.jboss.apiviz'
 [exec] [ERROR] artifactId = 'apiviz'
 [exec] [ERROR] version = '1.3.2.GA': Missing:
 [exec] [ERROR] ----------
 [exec] [ERROR] 1) com.sun:tools:jar:1.5.0
 [exec] [ERROR] 
 [exec] [ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
 [exec] [ERROR] 
 [exec] [ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
 [exec] [ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.sun -DartifactId=tools -Dversion=1.5.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
 [exec] [ERROR] 
 [exec] [ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
 [exec] [ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.sun -DartifactId=tools -Dversion=1.5.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
 [exec] [ERROR] 
 [exec] [ERROR] Path to dependency:
 [exec] [ERROR] 1) org.jboss.apiviz:apiviz:jar:1.3.2.GA
 [exec] [ERROR] 2) com.sun:tools:jar:1.5.0
 [exec] [ERROR] 
 [exec] [ERROR] ----------
 [exec] [ERROR] 1 required artifact is missing.
 [exec] [ERROR] 
 [exec] [ERROR] for artifact:
 [exec] [ERROR] org.jboss.apiviz:apiviz:jar:1.3.2.GA
 [exec] [ERROR] 
 [exec] [ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
 [exec] [ERROR] central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false),
 [exec] [ERROR] mobicents-public-repository-group (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public, releases=true, snapshots=true),
 [exec] [ERROR] jboss-public-repository-group (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/, releases=true, snapshots=true),
 [exec] [ERROR] restcomm-public-repository-group (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public, releases=true, snapshots=true),
 [exec] [ERROR] jboss-deprecated-repository (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/deprecated/, releases=true, snapshots=false)
 [exec] [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
 [exec] [ERROR] 
 [exec] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
 [exec] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [exec] [ERROR] 
 [exec] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
 [exec] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

BUILD FAILED
/tmp/workspace/Restcomm-Connect/release/build.xml:181: exec returned: 1

Just in case, I tried to follow the instructions from the error report regarding mvn install:install-file mvn and deploy:deploy-file, but didn't achieve any difference.

I just want to carry out a standard build of Restcomm Connect. Please can you advise?

Thank you. Best regards.